# Codeigniter Can't Find My_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Very frustrating - 
When I'm developing locally everything works perfect . I then started testing on my host (GoDaddy) for the first time and I get the error 
**Fatal error: Class 'MY_Model' not found in /home/content/49/12220009/html/application/models/user_model.php on line 3**

The code is very basic -

User_model.php

```
class User_model extends MY_Model {

protected  $_table;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_table = "user";
}
```

MY_Model.php (application/core/My_Model.php)

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
 public function __construct() {
    echo "in my model ctor";
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And it all starts with a controller loading User_model as expected -

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```

Any thoughts on why this would work locally but not on my host , or how to solve it in other words?

Comment: Could be a case-sensitivity issue; are you developing on Windows or Mac by any chance? Check the casing on your my_model filename; is it MY_Model.php or My_Model.php

Comment: Can you add this to your MY_Model, 
if(!class_exists('CI_Model')) { class CI_Model extends Model {  } } //  CI 2.0 Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

it is definitely a case-sensitivity issue; what you should do is follow these two steps

1.follow these conventions and you are good to go

```
 class Model_name extends CI_Model
```

**Model_name** is the name of your class... Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase

and then the file name should be in lower case like this

```
 application/models/model_name.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me:
on Linux system ,it show the error you specify while on window it was fine.

this is because Linux is ***case sensitivity*** .

what i did?;

> I rename the file from `/core/MY_model` to `/core/MY_Model`.

and ,then it solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

**CodeIgniter 3 solution**

The class name and the class filename must have an **uppercase first character**.

> Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries,
>   drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like
>   manner or in other words - they must start with a capital letter.

For example, if you have the following library file:

```
application/libraries/mylibrary.php
```

… then you’ll have to rename it to:

```
application/libraries/Mylibrary.php
```